# Modular JS and Prototypal Inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, modular

I'm trying to wrap my head around `prototypal inheritance` in JS. Is it possible for a module to borrow from another module's prototype?

The only way I've managed this so far is by accessing it down the `prototype chain`. Let's say, the first module hasn't created anything yet, is my second module just sol?

**Here's an example:**

```js
var Cars = (function ( make, serial ) {
 var obj = {};
 
 var Car = function () {
  this.make = make;
  this.serial = serial;
 }

 Car.prototype.drive = function () {
  console.log('vrrrooom')
 }

 obj[ serial ] = new Car()
 return {obj:obj}

}( 'Toyota', '12345' ))

var Vans = (function ( make, serial ){
 var obj = {}

 var Van = function () {
  this.make = make;
  this.serial = serial;
 }

 Van.prototype = Object.create ( Cars.obj[ '12345' ] )

 obj[ serial ] = new Van()
 return {obj:obj}

}( 'Ford', '6789' ))

// So the Toyota drives?
console.log( Cars.obj )
Cars.obj[ '12345' ].drive() // Cool!


// Maybe my Ford can too?
console.log( Vans.obj )
Vans.obj[ '6789' ].drive() // Cool, but what if there were no Cars?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `drive` method is called on the `Vans.obj[ '6789' ]`, JS first checks if the object itself has this property. It doesn't, so it checks its prototype `Cars.obj[ '12345' ]`. It also doesn't have this method, so the prototype of a that object, `Car.prototype`, is checked. The method is found there and executed on the `Vans.obj[ '6789' ]` object.

If `Cars.obj[ '12345' ]` was not defined ad the point of executing this line:

```
Van.prototype = Object.create ( Cars.obj[ '12345' ] )
```

JS would throw an error, since `undefined` is not allowed as the input to the `Object.create` method.

Comment: Great, so I've added these lines, return {obj:obj, drive: Car.prototype}, Van.prototype = Object.create ( Cars.drive ). That clears things up. Thank you!